# HERE maps starter example failed to load map

Tags: here-api

I literally just copy and paste the example code from the API documentation (link: https://developer.here.com/cn/documentation/maps/hls-chn/topics/quick-start.html)

and I put in my own app_id and app_code into the appropriate lines (for obvious reasons I cannot disclose my api key and code; sorry).

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <script src="https://js.hereapi.cn/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://js.hereapi.cn/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
  <script>
    // Initialize the platform object:
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'app_id': '{YOUR_APP_ID}',
    'app_code': '{YOUR_APP_CODE}'
    });

    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    maptypes.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the browser reported the following errors: [screenshot of errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbOjL.png):

This is what the webpage looks like: [the map does not display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N5NB.png)

The errors are confusing because the code snippet was not written by me, but directly copied from HERE Map's developer documentation. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you confirm your type of plan used? China specific SDKs and APIs are excluded from Freemimum or Pro plans.

Comment: As the error states it is a problem of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). Is this a solution for your question: https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/request-cross-domain-js.html ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using freemium plan then probably you should follow this documentation-

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.17.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started.html

and the below code-

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js"
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
    <script>



     // Initialize the platform object:
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': 'Your_api_key'
      });

      // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
      var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

      // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
      var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        maptypes.vector.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 10,
          center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```